# How to remove extra space while printing output of reversed string

Tags: c++, string, reverse

I am writing a program to reverse the order of words in a string.
If there is a sentence,

```
I love New York!
```

It should be changed to,

```
!York New love I
```

I'm reversing the order of words in a string by storing the last word and then adding space and then storing the second last and so on.
But when I print the output it adds a space before printing.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;
string reverse(string s){
    vector<string> temp;
    string words;
    stringstream ss(s);
    while (ss>>words)
    {
        temp.push_back(words);
    }
    string ans;
    for (int i = words.size()-1; i >=0; --i)
    {
        if (i!=words.size()-1)
        {
            ans+= " ";
        }
        ans+=temp[i];
    }
    return ans;
}
int main(){
    string s("My name is Saad Arshad ");
    cout<<reverse(s);
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
" Arshad Saad is name My"
```

I think the size of words is greater than that of temp thats why its happening but I still need more clarification.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: You are almost there. The linked comment from Jason would be a good start. You can also try printing just the first word and reading the code. You got this!

Comment: Side note: `for (int i = words.size()-1; i >=0; --i)` is a great place to use a reverse iterator. `for (auto it = word.rbegin(); it != rend(); ++it)`

Comment: You have tagged `dsa` (Digital Signature Algorithm).  I didn't see anything in your post about digital signatures.  Did I miss something?

Comment: Note, the algorithm you described should change "I love New York!" to "***York!*** New love I". Note where the exclamation mark is.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews its Data Structures and Algorithms

Comment: @Ranoiaetep yeah it should be but in my case I want to print it as !York. Any suggestion for printing it as YorK!??